# Why is the li expanding out of the ul?

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I made a simple list, and for the life of me I can't figure out why the li isn't sitting inside the ul as it should. Right now it expands to the right. I know it's something simple but it's driving me crazy. Please send help.

Here's the code:

```css
.big-ul{
  border-radius:8px;
  margin:20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.big-ul li{
  background-color:white;
  color:#333B66;
  padding:20px 15px 20px 15px;
  margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;
  border-radius:5px;
  border:.5px solid #E1E1E1;
  list-style-type:none;
  text-align:center;
  transition-duration:.5s;
}
```

```html
<ul class = "big-ul unitList">
    <li><a href = "8-options.html">Truck #1: ET</a></li>
    <li>Truck #2</li>
    <li>Truck #3</li>
    <li>Truck #4</li>
    <li>Truck #5</li>
    <li>Truck #6</li>
    <li>Truck #7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't sitting inside the ul" and "expands to the right"?  I don't see anything unexpected in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul` elements have a default `padding-left` css rule. Just remove it:

```css
.big-ul {
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
  padding: 0;
}

.big-ul li {
  background-color: white;
  color: #333B66;
  padding: 20px 15px 20px 15px;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: .5px solid #E1E1E1;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  transition-duration: .5s;

}
```

```html
<ul class="big-ul unitList">
  <li><a href="8-options.html">Truck #1: ET</a></li>
  <li>Truck #2</li>
  <li>Truck #3</li>
  <li>Truck #4</li>
  <li>Truck #5</li>
  <li>Truck #6</li>
  <li>Truck #7</li>
</ul>
```